# Covariant type in contravariant position (specific case)

Tags: scala, covariance

I know, there are many questions on SO with the same title, and I do understand what this error means in general, but this puzzles me:

```
trait Foo[A] { type F = A; def stuff(a: F): Unit; def mk(s: String): F }
abstract class Bar { self: Foo[_] => def moreStuff(a: F): Unit }
```

The first line is fine, but the second does not compile:
"covariant type _$1 occurs in contravariant position in type Bar.this.F of value a"

I can't make sense of this. 
Why does it think that `F` is covariant? It is an alias for `A`, which is invariant ... 
If `F` is covariant, why does the first line that declares `stuff(a: F)` not complain about it being in a contravariant position?

If I get rid of the type parameter, and make `F` abstract, then it works:

```
 trait Foo { type F; def stuff(a: F): Unit; def mk(s: String): F }
 class Bar { self: Foo => def moreStuff(a: F) = println(a) }
```

This is essentially the same thing as above. Why does this compile, and the other thing does not?

Also, if I keep the definition of `Foo`, but also parametrize `Bar`, that compiles too:

```
 class Bar[A] { self: Foo[A] => def moreStuff(a: F): Unit }
```

I would really like to get the first form to work. Is there any way to convince the compiler that `F` is really invariant?

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37056136/when-sharing-generics-across-traits-contravariant-error-for-parameters-of-tha

Comment: Similar, indeed. But no answer :(

Comment: I guess the thing is, if `A` (which is also `F`) is allowed to be a wildcard in `Foo`, then what is the signature of `moreStuff` meant to be?

Comment: @MichaelZajac it's `_$1` obviously :) Whatever the `.mk` returns. I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bug in 2.11. All of your examples compile fine in 2.12.